# Meaning of different terminals on AC start capacitors

Tags: capacitor, ac

I'm to change a failed start capacitor for an inline extractor fan motor in my home.
The original capacitor uses unipolar leads (both white) while the new one I selected uses twin cables (brown and blue) - see photos below.

The new capacitor is a Ducati Energia 416.15.01. The 416.87 series instead uses the same unipolar leads as the old cap - I'm trying to work out the difference. See the
[manufacturer specs](https://www.ducatienergia.com/media/products/220509-1202-condensatori-motori-new.pdf) (pages 13-16)

They're both for AC therefore I believe neither are polarised. Am I right assuming the new one is an appropriate equivalent? Can anyone explain why they use different leads - does that have any meaning?

*Original capacitor*
[image]

*New capacitor*
[image]

Comment: Could you please put a link to the datasheet or to the product page from a retailer, instead of a photo in which one of the important parameters cannot be seen?

Comment: Hi @RohatKılıç, I've edited the original question to include a better photo and the manufacturer datasheet. Thanks for your help

Comment: Should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen caps in this package but looking at the specs, I can say that the new one can be a replacement.

- They are both 2 μF ±5% / 450V. The new one indicates a life expectancy as well.
- Climatic categories are the same: -25/+85
- They both comply the ref standard of EN 60252-1.

The new one is a self-healing type metallised polypropylene capacitor. I couldn't find any useful information about the old one's such properties. Assuming the **MP**R4/C could be an indication of **m**etallised **p**olypropylene.

So the new one appears to be a replacement.

> Can anyone explain why they use different leads - does that have any meaning?

I don't think so. The old one simply uses a standard off-the-shelf 220V supply cable.